# How do I define a complex object class in PHP

Tags: php, class, object

I'm new to defining classes so I hope this isn't a trivial question.

I want to end up with a collection of data in an object that I access through parameters such as:

```
AllData->A->Discount->Amount 
AllData->A->Discount->Percentage
AllData->A->Claimed->Amount
AllData->A->Claimed->Percentage
```

I started with

```
class AllData
{
        public $Discount;
        public $Claimed;

 }
```

How do I defined the next levels (A, A->Amount, A->Percentage, etc.) of the object class?

Comment: you should elaborate whether all of the internal objects extends the same interface and have same properties

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an array?

Comment: An array would work in the simplest case as I've described it, but I'm trying to expand my understanding of classes and objects by using them.

Answer (score 2):

You should check \stdClass out.

```
class AllData
{
    public $Discount;
    public $Claimed;

    public function __construct() {
        $Discount = new \stdClass();
        $Discount->Amount = 100;
        $Discount->Percentage = 300;
    }
}
```

Now you can access the Discount Amount like this:

```
$object = new AllData();
echo $object->Discount->Amount;
```

This would be the fastest way as it seems you have classes that contain only attributes (so stdClass is fine for you).

Comment: I don't know why it didn't occur to me to use stdClass within a class.

Comment: Octavian's response has me on the right track but how do I go to the next level? If I want $Discount->Amount->USA and $Discount->Amount->CDN how do I define those? When I tried adding $Discount->Amount = new stdClass(), I get: "Warning: Creating default object from empty value"